# How to build a QAOA Ansatz

Tags: programming, qiskit, qaoa

I saw there is a qiskit package called "QAOAAnsatz" https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QAOAAnsatz.html.
But I didn't find out any tutorial related, so I have no idea how to use it.
Can anyone help me please? e.g. how to build parameter "cost_operator" etc. .

Comment: This tutorial will help: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/algorithms/05_qaoa.ipynb

Comment: @KAJ226 I have seen that link before, but it doesn't use QAOAAnsatz, thanks for your response anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at how the `QAOAAnsatz` class is used in the tests [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/fcedd7e17a21a9ac3dcc1891d38895c1bebca98a/test/python/circuit/library/test_qaoa_ansatz.py).

Note that the link given @KAJ226 in the question comments does not use `QAOAAnsatz` directly but use the `QAOA` class that forward the given operator to the `QAOAAnsatz` class. So when the line

```
result = qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
```

in cell 6 of [KAJ226 link](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/algorithms/05_qaoa.ipynb) is executed, it will call the `_check_operator_ansatz` with the exact same operator.
To summarise, the QAOAAnsatz class takes as parameter a `cost_operator` that can be constructed exactly like in cell n°5 of [KAJ226 link](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/algorithms/05_qaoa.ipynb).

The way you construct your operator depends on your particular cost function, so you will have to construct the operator by yourself, but you have a working example to start.

Answer (score 1):

The QAOAAnsatz was built for the QAOA algorithm, which if you look at the qaoa code in Qiskit you will see it builds a QAOAAnsatz instance internally. Hopefully looking at that helps you use it https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/5ca967557b21828c0760763b7f0c5870e5f032d9/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/qaoa.py#L131-L132

Comment: I tried to use it and got this result.
'QAOA' object has no attribute '_check_operator_ansatz'

Comment: That method is not intended to be called directly. I linked it to show you how the QAOAAnsatz was built in the context of QAOA so you could see what the cost operator etc was. The method is not found since it was changed from 0.17 to 0.18, and 0.18 is the version I linked to in main. (Actually 0.18 was released yesterday). For 0.17 its this https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/fa05da3fd8bd5ae95fc8dad08139edfa85378f93/qiskit/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/qaoa.py#L126